# HTML 5 <form> being weird

Tags: html, forms, web

So i'm currently building a set of 3 buttons via forms, and having a weird issue i've never seen before with the following code:

```
<div class='logout'>
  <form action='action.php' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' value='H'>
    <input type='text' name='mode' value='0' hidden>
  </form>
</div>
<div class='Mini'>
  <form action='action.php' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' value='M'>
    <input type='text' name='mode' value='MINI' hidden>
  </form>
</div>
<div class='Close'>
   <form action='action.php' method='post'>
     <input type='submit' value='C'>
     <input type='text' name='mode' value='DISPLAY' hidden>
  </form>
</div>
```

in its current state none of the forms are shown, but when the > is dropped from the close form tags they become fully functional

CSS is as follows

```
.logout{
    position:Absolute;
    left:90%;
    top:0%;
}
.Mini{
    position:Absolute;
    left:87%;
    top:0%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.Close{
    position:Absolute;
    left:-130%;
    top:0%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Are they _intended_ to be hidden with (eg) CSS on the `<div>`s perhaps?  It may be that dropping the `>` is causing the HTML to be parsed wrongly, and the classes/styles not being applied.  That's only one possibility though, there's not really enough information in your question to provide a proper diagnosis.

Comment: currently checking out the CSS files for issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code working perfect. May be some `css` of `div` overwrite your `form` and make it `display:none` or `hidden`.  If you remove `>` it will break some `css` and html. so you will be able to see all forms.

Here is the code run it and check :

```html
<div class='logout'>
  <form action='action.php' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' value='H'>
    <input type='text' name='mode' value='0' hidden>
  </form>
</div>
<div class='Mini'>
  <form action='action.php' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' value='M'>
    <input type='text' name='mode' value='MINI' hidden>
  </form>
</div>
<div class='Close'>
   <form action='action.php' method='post'>
     <input type='submit' value='C'>
     <input type='text' name='mode' value='DISPLAY' hidden>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: turns out since this was sitting around working as is for the last day or so, the CSS was built around the <div> tag being broken, had to realign the CSS for it

Comment: yes, i have check your css, you have wrong `left` align, instead you can use `float:left;`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here -->  [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/drctsp4j/)

Your elements show up.  I am assuming it's `CSS`  ...  There is nothing wrong with your HTML itself.  You need to look at your `CSS` styles and figure out why things aren't displaying.   Most likely it's going to be the `div` -->

`<div class='logout'>`

That's your issue.